# How can I configure exuberant-ctags to ignore python keyword arguments?

Tags: python, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm using exuberant-ctags to generate tags for my django project. In many places I'm calling functions and classes using keyword arguments.

```
$ cat models.py
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):

    bar = models.CharField(
        help_text='The very important "bar" field',
        unique=True,
        max_length=100,
    )
```

But when ctag parses these files, the keyword arguments are classified as variable declarations. This pollutes my tags files with a large number of false tags.

```
$ ctags -x models.py
Foo              class         3 models.py        class Foo(models.Model):
bar              variable      5 models.py        bar = models.CharField(
help_text        variable      6 models.py        help_text='The very important "bar" field',
max_length       variable      8 models.py        max_length=100,
unique           variable      7 models.py        unique=True,
```

I've read the [ctags docs](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html), but I couldn't find anything that seemed obviously relevant.

Is there some built-in functionality in ctags that I could use? Or will I have to pipe the tag file through something like `awk` to filter out the false matches?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug on `ctags` end, as per this PR : https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/pull/767

Make sure ctags is up to date, since the fix is now merged.

Since the pull request concerns multi-lines kwargs declaration, one can assume that putting them all on the same line will 'fix' the issue (but will most likely make your code break PEP8  recommendations).

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at universal-ctags, but I haven't switched to it yet, since it looks more bleeding edge than exuberant-ctags, and I would have to build it myself. I might have to reconsider if there's no simpler solution to this.

Comment: You should be able to prevent the issue by putting them all on one line, but this will probably make your linter very unhappy

Comment: That would make my code harder to read and maintain. Not worth it. I'm considering just stripping any match with a trailing `,` character from the generated `tags` file. But that would be quite hacky, and not 100% correct either.

Comment: Ok ! Just note that universal-ctags is not actually a new project, it's just a fork of exuberant-ctags after its development stopped, so you should be fine !